# How do I sum form fields values using Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have 5 input fields that I need to get the total of its SUM.

Created data fields and v-model to the fields and at computed: i'm trying to do the SUM

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="ValorImovelPatrimonio" name="ValorImovelPatrimonio" v-model="ValorImovelPatrimonio" required @keydown="$event.keyCode === 13 ? $event.preventDefault() : false" @blur="pegaTotal">
```

```
 var vue = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            checked : false,
            deposito: 1,
            patrimonio_nao: false,
            ValorImovelPatrimonio: null,
            ValorAutosPatrimonio: null,
            ValorOutrosPatrimonio: null,
            ValorAcoesPatrimonio: null,
            ValorInvestimentosPatrimonio: null,
            // total: null
        },
...
```

```
computed: {
                total: function(){
                    return this.ValorImovelPatrimonio + this.ValorAutosPatrimonio;
                }
            }
```

What happens:

```
ValorAutosPatrimonio:"15.000"
ValorImovelPatrimonio:"1.500.000"
```

```
total:"1.500.00015.000"
```

But I expect:

```
1.515.000
```

Anyone, please?

Comment: try explicit conversion float(this.ValorImovelPatrimonio) + float(this.ValorAutosPatrimonio)

Comment: Note that `ValorAutosPatrimonio` and `ValorImovelPatrimonio` are strings. You need to convert them to numbers before doing any arithmetic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to cast that data to numbers like :

```
return parseFloat(this.ValorImovelPatrimonio) + parseFloat(this.ValorAutosPatrimonio);
```

Comment: Works! But the sum is wrong. It gave 16.5 and I expect 1,515.000 (millions)

Comment: Hummmm, the problem is the vue-the-mask. The sum was right without it

Comment: try `return parseFloat(this.ValorImovelPatrimonio.replace(/./g,'')) + parseFloat(this.ValorAutosPatrimonio.replace(/./g,''));`

Comment: Thanks, @Boussadjra Brahim!